# sticky-kit content disappears at bottom of scroll

Tags: jquery, html, sticky

I'm using [sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) to scroll content and then fix once it reaches the end of the content of one column.

Here are some examples of the sticky-kit working fine on my website:
[Example 1](http://meganhutchinson.co.uk/sarah-price/2015/09/20/im-a-lovely-title/), [Example 2](http://meganhutchinson.co.uk/sarah-price/2015/09/20/new-york-fasion-week/)

However I have run into an issue that when you reach the bottom of [this post](http://meganhutchinson.co.uk/sarah-price/2015/09/20/a-fresh-new-take-on-denim/) the right hand content is disappearing? Which I dont understand why as its using the exact same code as the other post content.

I have looked into reference of sticky-kit and it says that adding a `sticky_kit:recalc` should help with issues like this. But it hasn't made any difference.

Here is my code:

```
$(document.body).trigger("sticky_kit:recalc");
$("#single__images, #single__content").stick_in_parent({offset_top:150});
```

HTML:

```
<article id="single-post">
     <div id="single__images><img src="#"></div>
     <div id="single__content>Text goes here</div>
</article>
```

Does anyone have any idea on what could be causing the content to disappear and how to solve it?

Comment: Could you try to remove the `margin-bottom: 100px` from the following `.type-post` element, and add that to the `#sigle__images` element. That way you can`t reach the total height when scrolling all the way down, which should keep the sticky right content in place.

Answer (score 4):

I had also the same issue that my sticky div disappears at the bottom. I used it for bootstrap cols. I solved it by adding position: static to the sticky id. Either by jQuery:

```
$('#my-sticky-element')
.on('sticky_kit:bottom', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().css('position', 'static');
})
.on('sticky_kit:unbottom', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
})
```

Or simply by CSS:

```
#my-sticky-element {
   position: static
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my project I had to solve by changing the columns, which had `position:relative;` to `position:static;`

When nearing the part of the layout where The Sticky element changes to `unstick`, it's position changes from `position:fixed;` to `position:absolute;`. If the designated parent element is not the immediate parent, then any elements in between that have a relative or absolute position will screw up the sticky element's position.